# Does Japanese use litotes?

Tags: colloquial-language, rhetoric

Are [litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) and similar understatement typically used in Japanese?

The Japanese Wikipedia [entry on litotes](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B7%A9%E5%8F%99%E6%B3%95) is no *War and Peace*, which makes me suspect they don't use them very often.

Comment: I'm not sure the length of the Wikipedia article is a super useful metric; Japanese is fairly compact as a language to begin with, and the English article is kind of all over the place.

Comment: It depends on what counts as a litotes. With the definition and examples the article gave, something like 高くない would be one, meaning "it's not expensive/tall" (negative of "it is cheap/short"), and that is certainly possibly to say.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't think the use of litotes is language(or country?)-specific.

Some people are fond of rhetorics, while others prefer direct expressions. That's all, I guess.